# \newcommand doesn't work with \section and \chapter

Tags: macros, sectioning

I have a newcommand defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\met}{\cancel{\it{E}}_{T}}
```

When I try to place it into a \section like this:

```
\chapter{\met}
```

I get error messages like this:

! Undefined control sequence.
\met ->{\cancel 
                {\it {E}}_{T}}

I am using TeXworks with miktex 2.9 on Windows 7.

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Why is there a backslash in front of the closing brace?

Comment: Now that the aforementioned backslash is gone, the error message changed as well. Seems you didn't load package `cancel` or `met` isn't defined. Hard to tell without the [needed information](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: btw: the underscore will throw a missing math error, and the `\it{<argument>}` doesn't exist as well.

Comment: It might be easier, if you tell us, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My mistake, I've updated the post with the error I am seeing, it is actually an undefined control sequence.

Comment: You haven't given any clues as to what you did, is the `\newcommand` after `\tableofcontents` for example (which will give that error) `\cancel` and `_` are math mode constructs but you have given no indication that you are using math mode. `\it` should not be used in latex but if it is used the syntax is `{\it E}` not `\it{E}`

Comment: I found the solution from one of the comments here. First, I needed to load package cancel, and then I had to use $\met$ instead of \met

Comment: @DavidCarlisle or rather `{\itshape E}` or `\textit{E}`

Comment: @Johannes_B `\itshape` won't work in math mode (which is I assume the intended context here once other errors fixed)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I assumed text mode ;-) Variables will be typeset italic by default.

Answer (score 5):

Please always post complete documents, as below, not just fragments.

If I start with

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\met}{\cancel{\it{E}}_{T}}

\chapter{\met}

\end{document}
```

I get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\met ->\cancel
```

so change to

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\met}{\cancel{\it{E}}_{T}}

\chapter{\met}

\end{document}
```

I get

```
! You can't use `\/' in vertical mode.
\@cancel ...ht \unitlength \p@ \canc@thinlines {\/
```

Which is maybe a bit harder to understand but `\cancel` is supposed to be in math mode, so not at the start of a paragraph in vertical mode. so

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\met}{$\cancel{\it{E}}_{T}$}

\chapter{\met}

\end{document}
```

which produces

```
Output written on file.pdf (1 page, 33145 bytes).
```

[image]

Which is sort of OK except that `\it` has been deprecated since LaTeX2e was introduced in 1993, and if it is used the syntax is `{\it E}` not `\it{E}` You could use `\mathit{E}` which is the correct markup to get the previous image but probably you want math italic for which you just need `E`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\met}{$\cancel{E}_{T}$}

\chapter{\met}

\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]